# How would a bulk payload like fuel (instead of delicate technology) change boost to LEO optimization?

Tags: rockets, low-earth-orbit, trajectory, launch-vehicle, g-force

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17960/12102) suggests that if a payload were simply bulk propellant, such as LH2 and LOX, and not delicate technology such as an interplanetary probe or communications satellite, then there may be some re-optimization of launch trajectory and perhaps the launch vehicle, to incorporate such things as a higher g-force trajectory.

I know that early in a launch, the thrust (and therefore g-force) is sometimes *even reduced* so that the total compression forces on the rocket body (rocket thrust pushing up at one end, aerodynamic drag pushing down at the other) is capped at ["Max-Q"](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17112/12102) - see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Q) - so how much could it actually be increased?

**Question:** How would a bulk payload like fuel (instead of delicate technology) change boost to LEO optimization?

Comment: In the extreme example of human launches (most fragile payload) in lunar launches engines were shut off to reduce g-load and extra mass had to be added as a launch escape system to save the crew in case of failure

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but apparently the launch profile (in particular, how steeply a rocket climbs initially) is a bit more shallow for **at least some** crewed vehicles. This is done to allow for a better choice of aborts if the engines stop early in the launch. (A fall from a great height with little forward speed is likely to give a more difficult re-entry trajectory.) This isn't worthwhile for un-crewed launches, as everything is expendable.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Max Q has as much to do with conserving Delta-V as it does preventing aerodynamic RUD. It's easier to throttle back and wait til you're in thinner air than it is to try to fight through the huge drag-losses of Max Q. That's what I remember, anyway.

Comment: @UIDAlexD that's interesting, and potentially the makings of a good question - in what cases reason A, or reason B, or both..

Comment: @uhoh: actually, that's a middle ground / consequence, three factors influencing each other. Exceeding MaxQ would lead to delta-V losses; since MaxQ won't be exceeded there's no point to make the rocket withstand higher dynamic pressures; as result exceeding MaxQ would result in RUD. (also, lightening the construction leads to different aerodynamic profile, which causes drag, and the threshold of delta-V loss, which changes the desirable MaxQ, closing the loop.)

Comment: @SF. that's a lot of good information but it really should be expanded into an answer - the comment format is so short and I can't quite get all of that packaged so tightly. If it hasn't been asked already, I'll give it a try in a day or so. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't there be a point of max Q no matter how you tweak the launch profile? You could *move* the point of max Q, but there will always be a point of maximum dynamic pressure during the ascent through the atmosphere.

Comment: There is normally a flight rule on the maximum allowed dynamic pressure, the trajectory and throttling is designed to not exceed this. Should really be called the q limit. But yes, every trajectory will have a point of maximum dynamic pressure "max q"

Answer (score 1):

The bulk payload like fuel may tolerate high g-forces and strong vibrations, but the tanks and the structure of the rocket body must be built for high g-forces also. Not easy if the tanks and the structure should be as light as possible to maximize the amount of bulk payload. A payload of LOX and LH2 would require thermal insulation to limit the loss by boil-out.

Comment: The context is [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/17958/12102) and the presentation linked there, as well as [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/17960/12102) that I've linked to. Presumably it is possible to make tank payloads that can handle greater static and/or dynamic g-forces than *deep space probe* or *communications satellite* payloads. In that case, how would that change the "Boost to LEO" trajectory optimization?

Answer (score 1):

As a rather violent "boost optimization", I'd like to point out to the existing question about unconventional LEO launching, where [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3034/12519) provides a nice presentation of a **gas gun**. A quick summary is: gas gun was tested to provide at least 3 km/s initial delta-v. The bullet is planned to be a small rocket. The technology is currently ready for a high-G rocket - with electronics included! Fuel is explicitly said to be an ideal high-G payload. Cost to LEO per pound of fuel is calculated there, but it's so absurdly low I'd dare not repeat it here :)

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer specifically to this question, or is this just a comment or passing thought?

Comment: An answer. You haven't narrowed the question to the conventional rockets. Using a gas gun is "boost" optimization, just a rather violent one.

Comment: OK you've piqued my interest! Can you summarize a bit some of the info that's in that answer and video? Roughly how many G's are we actually  talking about here? Lifting liquids is very different than lifting solids - if you push on them they like to expand sideways. Does that answer and/or video talk about the extra mass of the tank necessary to contain liquids?

Comment: Actually I just realized that this is exactly what @Uwe is talking about in [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/18226/12102).